# how to create a php extension for an object?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, php-extension

I am working on a php extension for c++ classes. How to create a link to a method that accepts as parameter an object of a class?

Can you give me some examples?
THX. APPRECIATE!

I succedded to create a link to a method that accepts as parameter a string or int. But I don't know how to do this for a method.

Here is a short example:

```
PHP_METHOD(Class1, method_string)
{
    Class1 *access;
    char *strr=NULL;

    int strr_len;
     if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "s", &strr, &strr_len) == FAILURE) {
        RETURN_NULL();
    }
    access_object *obj = (access_object *)zend_object_store_get_object(
        getThis() TSRMLS_CC);
    access = obj->access;
    if (access != NULL) {
        std::string s(strr);
       RETURN_BOOL(access->method_string(s));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `ZEND_API int zend_parse_method_parameters(int num_args TSRMLS_DC, zval *this_ptr, char *type_spec, ...);` AND
`ZEND_API int zend_parse_method_parameters_ex(int flags, int num_args TSRMLS_DC, zval *this_ptr, char *type_spec, ...);` are the right API for retrieving the input parameters in the method.

I think the same API will help you accept an object as an input parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Use the zend API `zend_parse_method_parameters()`:

```
ZEND_METHOD(ext_access_class, do_something)
{
    zval* objid_this = NULL, objid1 = NULL;

    // note: ext_access_class_entry and ext_param_class_entry are of type zend_class_entry*
    if (zend_parse_method_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, getThis(), "OO", &objid_this, ext_access_class_entry, &objid1, ext_param_class_entry) == FAILURE)
        RETURN_NULL();


    ext_access_class* const access_obj = (ext_access_class*) zend_object_store_get_object(objid_this TSRMLS_CC);
    Class1* const access = access_obj->access;

    ext_param_class* const param_obj = (ext_param_class*) zend_object_store_get_object(objid1 TSRMLS_CC);
    Class2* const myobject = param_obj->myobject;


    const bool ret = access->do_something(myobject);

    RETURN_BOOL(ret);
}
```